# What determines when a collection is created?

Tags: collections, clojure, side-effects

If I understand correctly Clojure can return lists (as in other Lisps) but also vectors and sets.

What I don't really get is why there's not **always** a collection that is returned.

For example if I take the following code:

```
(loop [x 128]
  (when (> x 1)
    (println x)
    (recur (/ x 2))))
```

It does print 128 64 32 16 8 4 2.  But that's only because *println* is called and *println* has the side-effect (?) of printing something.

So I tried replacing it with this (removing the println):

```
(loop [x 128]
  (when (> x 1)
    x
    (recur (/ x 2))))
```

And I was expecting to get some collecting (supposedly a list), like this:

```
(128 64 32 16 8 4 2)
```

but instead I'm getting *nil*.

I don't understand which determines what creates a collection and what doesn't and how you switch from one to the other.  Also, seen that Clojure somehow encourages a "functional" way of programming, aren't you supposed to nearly always return collections?

Why are so many functions that apparently do not return any collection?  And what would be an idiomatic way to make these return collections?

For example, how would I solve the above problem by first constructing a collection and then iterating (?) in an idiomatic way other the resulting list/vector?

First I don't know how to transform the *loop* so that it produces something else than *nil* and then I tried the following:

```
(reduce println '(1 2 3))
```

But it prints *"1 2nil 3nil"* instead of the *"1 2 3nil"* I was expecting.

I realize this is basic stuff but I'm just starting and I'm obviously missing basic stuff here.

*(P.S.: retag appropriately, I don't know which terms I should use here)*

Comment: Your understanding of `when` is wrong, you should be using `if`. And even then you'd be returning `x` which is a number. You actually have to create a list from somewhere to return one.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: ok but... My question is how to determine what is going to create what: for example why does *when* not work here and how could I know?  Does this mean that *when* should only be used inside functions that have side-effects?

Comment: @CedricMartin There is no magic in functional programming.  Returning a number does just that—return a number, nothing else.  (And in your case, since the number is returned to a context that doesn't care about return values (a `when` body clause in non-tail position), it gets discarded right away, so nothing at all happens.)  If you want a collection, you need to create it explicitly.  Regarding the use of `when`: `when` is precisely intended *for* side effects, so while learning functional programming, it's best to avoid it.

Comment: @MatthiasBenkard - Why do you say 'when is precisely intended for side-effects'? Is it not just a short form of if, ie. an if with no else clause?

Comment: @sw1nn It has no else-clause, yes—but `if` doesn't require the else-clause, either (it's optional).  The point of `when` is the implicit `do`, which is of no use for side-effect-free code.

Comment: @Matthias Benkard: *"The point of when is the implicit do, which is of no use for side-effect-free code"*... This is all very new to me. I don't know exactly why I asked, before your comment: *"Does this mean that when should only be used inside functions that have side-effects?"*... It was just some kind of "guess". But both Lisp and "functional programming" are new to me so it's a bit of a mindset shift at the beginning. I may ask a new question, with a better formulation. Thanks for your help and +1 btw : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few other comments have pointed out that when doesn't really work like if - but I don't think that's really your question.

The loop and recur forms create an iteration - like a for loop in other languages.  In this case, when you are printing, it is indeed just for the side effects.  If you want to return a sequence, then you'll need to build one:

```
(loop [x 128                                                                                                        
       acc []]                                                                                                      
  (if (< x 1)                                                                                                       
    acc                                                                                                             
    (recur (/ x 2)                                                                                                  
           (cons x acc))))                                                                                          

=> (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128)
```

In this case, I replaced the spot where you were calling printf with a recur *and* a form that adds x to the front of that accumulator.  In the case that x is less than 1, the code returns the accumulator - and thus a sequence.  If you want to add to the end of the vector instead of the front, change it to conj:

```
(loop [x 128                                                                                                    
       acc []]                                                                                                  
  (if (< x 1)                                                                                                   
    acc                                                                                                         
    (recur (/ x 2)                                                                                              
           (conj acc x))))                                                                                      

=> [128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1]
```

You were getting nil because that was the result of your expression -- what the final println returned.

Does all this make sense?

reduce is not quite the same thing -- it is used to reduce a list by repeatedly applying a binary function (a function that takes 2 arguments) to either an initial value and the first element of a sequence, or the first two elements of the sequence for the first iteration, then subsequent iterations are passed the result of the previous iteration and the next value from the sequence.  Some examples may help:

```
(reduce + [1 2 3 4])                                                                                            

10
```

This executes the following:

```
(+ 1 2) => 3
(+ 3 3) => 6
(+ 6 4) => 10
```

Reduce will result in whatever the final result is from the binary function being executed -- in this case we're reducing the numbers in the sequence into the sum of all the elements.

You can also supply an initial value:

```
(reduce + 5 [1 2 3 4])                                                                                            

15
```

Which executes the following:

```
(+ 5 1)  => 6
(+ 6 2)  => 8
(+ 8 3)  => 11
(+ 11 4) => 15
```

HTH,

Kyle

Comment: +1, it makes a lot of sense.  It was the side-effect of *println* that kinda disoriented me: I didn't understand why *nil* was what was thrown at the end.  But now it's way clearer.  Of course probably more questions too... : )

Answer (score 2):

The generalized abstraction over collection is called a sequence in Clojure and many data structure implement this abstraction so that you can use all sequence related operations on those data structure without thinking about which data structure is being passed to your function(s).

As far as the sample code is concerned - the loop, recur is for recursion - so basically any problem that you want to solve using recursion can be solved using it, classic example being factorial. Although you can create a vector/list using loop - by using the accumulator as a vector and keep appending items to it and in the exist condition of recursion returning the accumulated vector - but you can use `reductions` and `take-while` functions to do so as shown below. This will return a lazy sequence.

Ex:

```
(take-while #(> % 1) (reductions (fn [s _] (/ s 2)) 128 (range)))
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `(take-while #(> % 1) (iterate #(/ % 2) 128))`